# Uso de “ermão” em vez de “irmão” no português do Brasil

Tags: ortografia, português-brasileiro, informalidade

Tenho vários amigos brasileiros, e muitas vezes, quando trocamos sms, é usual virem escritas palavras que me fazem duvidar da sua correção gramatical. Por exemplo, já li mensagens com palavras como «Ermão» em vez de «Irmão», etc.

A minha dúvida é: estas palavras realmente existem, ou se são apenas coloquialmente aceites quando já há alguma confiança entre as pessoas?

Comment: Até onde sei é errado. Se é um erro proposital ou não, nem sempre é possível concluir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não, não existem. São apenas palavras escritas erradas intencionalmente, como uma brincadeira com o som das letras das palavras.

Outros exemplos são "a zamiga" (as amigas), "amiguenho" (amiguinho), "kibe surdo" (que absurdo), etc.

É uma prática informal, portanto não se deve fazer isso quando formalidade é esperada.

Mas claro, isso se foi proposital. Caso a pessoa tenha usado E achando que o som de I é só costume, e não a letra em si, aí seria nada mais do que um erro mesmo.

Comment: Bruno, e no caso em que escrevem 'fizesse' em vez de 'fizeste',etc.? Podemos dizer que é a mesma prática?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Hmm, pode ser ou não. Depende muito do caso. Mas, no geral, ***eu*** diria que não, parece ser um outro caso não relacionado com isso.

Comment: Confesso que esta resposta está bem meia boca, mas não há como apresentar evidências para um costume de linguagem informal. Usei como base a minha vivência.

Comment: @BrunoLopes às vezes tem de ser mesmo coma base na vivencia, porque são coisas recentes. Aqui em Portugal também usamos alguns casos desses para dar ênfase ao sotaque da região. Por exemplo, "quero buber binho" (quero beber vinho). Mas não confundir os erros propositados com quem erra por não saber.

Comment: "kibe surdo"...essa é nova pra mim =P